# Designing a count based access control

Tags: java, algorithm, architecture

I would like to get some advice on designing a count based access control. For example I want to restrict the number of users that a customer can create in my system based on their account. So by default a customer can create 2 users but if the upgrade their account they get to create 5 users and so on.
There are a few more features that I need to restrict on a similar basis.

The application follows a generic model so every feature exposed has a backing table and we have a class which handles the CRUD operation on that table. Also the application runs on multiple nodes and has a distributed cache.

The approach that I am taking to implement this is as follows
- I have a new table which captures the functionality to control and the allowed limit (stored per customer).
- I intercept the create method for all tables and check if the table in question needs to have access control applied. If so I fetch the count of created entities and compare against the limit to decide if I should allow the creation or not.
- I am using the database to handle synchronization in case of concurrent requests. So after the create method is called I update the table using the following where clause

> where ( count_column + 1 ) = #countInMemory#

. i.e. the update will succeed only if the value stored in the DB + 1 = value in memory. This will ensure that even if two threads attempt a create at the same time, only one of them will be able to successfully update. The thread that successfully updates wins and the other one is rolled back. This way I do not need to synchronize any code in the application.

I would like to know if there is any other / better way of doing this. My application runs on Oracle and MySQL DB.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

When you roll back, do you retry (after fetching the new user count) or do you fail? I recommend the former, assuming that the new fetched user count would permit another user.

I've dealt with a similar system recently, and a few things to consider: do you want CustomerA to be able to transfer their users to CustomerB? (This assumes that customers are not independent, for example in our system CustomerA might be an IT manager and CustomerB might be an accounting manager working for the same company, and when one of CustomerA's employees moves to accounting he wants this to be reflected by CustomerB's account.) What happens to a customer's users when the customer is deleted? (In our case another customer/manager would need to adopt them, or else they would be deleted.) How are you storing the customer's user limit - in a separate table (e.g. a customer has type "Level2," and the customer-type table says that "Level2" customers can create 5 users), or in the customer's row (which is more error prone, but would also allow a per-customer override on their max user count), or a combination (a customer has a `type` column that says they can have 5 users, and an `override` column that says they can have an additional 3 users)?

But that's beside the point. Your DB synchronization is fine.

Comment: In order to simplify code, I do not retry. Rather just throw an exception, your point though is a valid one.
Also I do not have the scenarios that you describe, users are associated with a customer for the lifetime of the customer.
Finally I store the count per row as that allows me to override the limit easily.